# MySQL query between 2 dates fields

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create a MySQL query that will take current date and compare it to the 2 date fields that i have in my table and return the rows that satisfy that query.

here is my columns
1- [from_date] which type is Date
2- [to_date] which also holds type Date

the query suppose to return the rows that falls in between those dates.

here is my query

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM location WHERE from_date >= DATE() AND to_date <= DATE()")
```

my problem is that it doesn't return anything.
should i switch my column type to DATETIME?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you got your answer you should accept the answer buddy. its just not like you come, ask a question, get your answer and run away..

Comment: sorry new to this forum, dont know where is the answer buddy, ive been looking for it but cant find it. can you point me to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation here.
Use `BETWEEN`

[mysql documentation here](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/190132)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `Now()` to get the current date of the system.

Comment: `NOW()` gives current date **and time**. `CURRENT_DATE()` gives the current date.

Answer (score 1):

use [between](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm)

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM location WHERE CURDATE() between from_date and to_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try NOW() insted of DATE()

```
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM location WHERE from_date >= NOW() AND to_date <= NOW()")
```

Get more about NOW() [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

Comment: Thanks everyone, i went with

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM location WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN from_date AND to_date")

and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DATE()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) actually just extracts the date part from a date or datetime expression. It doesn't, however, **not** return the current date as you intend.

To get the current time use [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) or [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM location WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN from_date AND to_date")
```

If trying to find a something between two values, MySQL also has the [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator